# Auto-Indent Code In Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: dreamweaver, indentation

This is getting really irritating and I can't seem to figure out how to disable this feature.  I notice that if I use a [ in a line and then press enter and then close an if statement with }, it will automatically indent to the same column as the [ in the previous line.  Is there any way to disable this feature?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm currently being driven crazy by the same "feature"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Go to the View menu and select Code View Options and then disable Auto Indent.